# gcc linker: forcing library dependency

Tags: python, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, cython

I am building a shared library with a few dependencies, including `readline` and `ncurses`:

```
g++ -m64 -shared -o lib/libXYZ.so <some .o files> -lz -lgmp -lreadline -lncurses
```

The dependency to `ncurses` is not showing up, though,  when I run `ldd` on the generated library:

```
ldd lib/libXYZ.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe5399e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd9d4d9e000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fd9d4b2a000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fd9d48e4000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd9d45e0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd9d42da000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd9d40c4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd9d3cff000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fd9d3ad6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd9d59f5000)
```

When I try to use this library `libX` to generate a C application, everything's working fine.

Using it to build Cython code results in a broken Python module:

```
 ImportError: <python-environment>/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
```

**Solution Attempt 1**

Explicitly add `ncurses` to the list of libraries when building the Python modules.

I don't like this, since all dependencies should be contained in `libX`.

**Solution Attempt 2**

Force the Python module to use the same `readline` lib that the C code originally linked to. `ncurses` is required because of `readline` and my anaconda Python environment ships has its own version of `readline` that is used because of the set runtime library path. If I remove the `libreadline.so` from this path, the linker will use my global library and the `ncurses` dependency is not causing any difficulties.

This is obivously a hack and forces users to mess with their Python environment.

**Preferred Solution (don't know how)**

*Simply* force the dependency of `ncurses` when the library `libX` was built with `readline`.

Is there any way to do this with the gcc/g++ linker?

**EDIT**

Apparently, the `readline` package of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) is not needed to build the Python module. Removing it solves the issue - most likely because then the same `readline` lib is used that `libXYZ` was linked to.

Comment: Add a call to a function from `libncurses.so` from a (dummy) function inside `libXYZ.so` — then it will need the library.

Comment: Yes, that would be an option, but I don't want to modify the lib itself.